# POST for @JoinColumn attributes in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a `log` table like this which has the following columns :

- id (primary key auto increment)
- asset (varchar)
- seen_by (integer) (holds user_id)

I have another `user` table, which is like :

- user_id (primary key auto increment)
- name (varchar)

My Log entity has a `@OneToOne` and `@JoinColumn` to `User` entity, so `Log` entity has `seenBy` as type `User`.
So the `Log` JSON resource looks like this :

```
{
"id" : "1",
"asset" : "something",
"seenBy" : 
{"userId" : "11",
"name" : "some user"}
}
```

This works fine for a GET request. But for a POST request, I have to post the whole `User` resource, which I don't want to do.

So, what I want is, in GET the `Log` JSON should stay the same which 'seenBy' as `User' type. But for POST request I only want to send the`userId`. So the JSON resource should look like this for POST :

```
{
"id" : "1",
"asset" : "something",
"seenBy" : "11"
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

**P.S.** I am using Spring Boot 1.5.3.  MySql as database. And Spring Data Jpa.

Comment: sounds like not very good design decision. if your goal is to create new Log resource with post you either provide user or leave it as null (you don't need to provide all the information it can be smth. like `"seenBy" : { "userId" : 11 }`) or just add another property like "seenById" and populate it on post but that looks also not that good

Comment: @john let me try this one

Comment: I am not sure but I think a OneToOne mapping does not seem correct here to me. I think it should be a ManyToOne mapping because there might be many log entries seen by the same user.

Comment: @Markus well that is true, but it is a one sided mapping. Meaning the User side does not have any relation to Log. I just want User in the seenBy of Log. But do not want to POST in every create / update requests.

Comment: Yes, but mapping a ManyToOne does not mean it has to be in both directions.

Comment: @Markus consider that, it is only one on one

Answer (score -1):

There is a way of doing it.

Approach is to Define your class in way such that there is no direct mapping of USER and LOG table. But only an ID in the LOG table as a LONG or INTEGER field. Pass both the user and log in the backend as a DTO object . Get the ID from the user object and set in the log ID field.

Comment: I am not looking for this.